# Docker container restarting in a loop on GCE

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have correctly deployed a Docker container which  runs a Python script that grabs some data from the internet and slaps it in BigQuery. The container works well on my machine and on a GCE instance that I've provisioned.

Now, everything works well for the most part but I am failing to understand why the docker container **always** restarts after exiting (apparently correctly). Logs, in this case, seems to be fairly useless as there is no error whatsoever. My current hunch is that something is failing silently, forcing the instance to restart.

Is there any way to find out the reboot reason for a given Docker container?

#### Things tried so far

1. I've tried to print the exit code of the container in the following way. The result is always 0, no matter those restart cycles.

```sh
while true
do 
    docker inspect my_container --format='{{.State.ExitCode}}'
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#viewing_logs) provides you different ways in which you can review your container related logs including container starts and stops.

In any way, I think there is no problem with your container: by default Compute Engine will restart a container on exit, although you can specify a different restart policy if you need to. Please, see the [relevant documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers#specifying_a_restart_policy).

Comment: One of the biggest facepalms of my life.